# Performance on a Temporary Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm in a legacy situation and I have a very large dynamic SQL query running on SQL 2k.  I can't use TABLE return functions and I my dynamic SQL is limited to varchar(8000) which I'm now exceeding.  It was using a UDF that was VERY slow and I was pulling the logic into the main query to avoid it.  However, this pushed me over 8000 and in SQL 2k I can't pass in varchar(MAX) above 8k.  I could use EXEC and concatenate a string but that will slow it down and not allowing caching.

Part of the query is a very complex pricing calculation which takes price type and user variables.  Then using these it looks up the price values (operator, amount, type of conversion) and then uses this and the specific price type (one of about a dozen) to calculate the users Authorized Cost.

After this cost is calculated we use it to limit models returned based on price from and to and also a margin price from and to (another calculation).  I am thinking that instead of doing all the calculations on they fly I will just pull all the products that meet other criteria and dump them into a temporary table, calculate the price and store it in that temp table, then select the subset that meets the price and margin price criteria from the temporary table.

Right now it's all in a single SELECT. How much does it affect efficiency, or does it, if I grab a larger dataset and insert it into a temporary table and then pull the subset from this table versus doing it all in a single SELECT.  It seems like it's wasteful to grab and stash 10k records and stash them when I only need 2000 of them.  But I'm wondering if that's what SQL engine is doing anyway internally and if it's that big of a difference.

So basically it would be (very simplified)....

```
SELECT model, (authorizedPriceCalculationLogic) FROM models WHERE (authorizedPriceCalculationLogic) Between @from and @to AND  (authorizedPriceCalculationLogic)/retailPrice*100 Between @marginFrom and @marginTo

AND

INSERT INTO #tempProducts
SELECT mode, retailPrice, price 1, price 2, price 3...price 12, priceType, priceOperator, priceAmount FROM models

UPDATE #tempProducts SET authPrice = (authorizedPriceCalculationLogic), authPriceMargin = (authorizedPriceCalculationLogic)/retailPrice*100

SELECT model, authorizedPrice FROM #tempProducts WHERE authorizedPrice Between @from and @to AND authPriceMargin Between @marginFrom and @marginTo
```

Comment: A temp table with 10k records is probably fine performance-wise, in my experience. Why not just try it?

Comment: Why not move that authorizedPriceCalculationLogic bit to a function, which of course would make your query much shorter.

Comment: Refactor that mess! Create some functions/SP to handle the logic and that 8000k ill drop to a few lines.

Comment: I had everything in a couple scalar UDF's but it was killing performance.  The reason it's ballooned is I am trying to get out of the UDF's.   I'm trying to get them to upgrade server and I can use Table Functions and kill this whole mess, but kind of stuck right now.

Comment: Blorgbear, I'm going to try it.  It's quite a mess to change it and I'm going to move forward and test but I was looking for some general feedback on how SQL engine actually processed the SELECT.  Is grabbing a bunch of records into temp table and then selecting a subset much different than SQL grabbing that subset right form the get go. Also, I said 10k records but in some searches it could be as much as 50-60k.  10k  was an arbitrary number, I should have been more specific.